# Find averages by index

Tags: excel, average

I have a slightly complicated task that I need to do in Excel. I have a spreadsheet that is 10,000 rows by 100 columns. I want to extract the 10 groups that are 1000 rows by 100 columns from that spreadsheet. Then I want to get a row of the averages of each of the 100 columns for each of the groups I got previously.

Then I want to copy each of the averages 500 times so that I have 500 rows of the averages from the first group, then 500 more rows with averages from the second group and so on.

This is a lot to do by hand, so I was wondering if there are any parts of it that I can easily automate. I'm not familiar with scripting in Excel, but I feel like a lot of these things can be done with built in functions.

Comment: Can you clarify the part about 500 rows? Breaking 10,000 into 10x1000 sounds straightforward, but it's unclear to me how you select 500 row averages from the groups of 1000 rows.

Comment: What's a good way to break the 1000 rows into groups of 10?
As for the next part, once i have a group, i want to find the average in the group of each column.
Then I want to make a row with the averages of each column.
Then i want to repeat that row 500 times.
Then repeat the process for each group. I hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is labelled for Columns and starts in A2, insert a column on the extreme left with, in A2:

```
=1+INT((ROW()-2)/1000)
```

copied down to suit.  Select and Copy ColumnA then Paste Special, Values over the top. Select ColumnsA:CW, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, Use function: Average and check all entries in Add subtotal to: (with Replace current subtotals and Summary below data also checked).

Select and Copy entire sheet, Paste Special, Values over the top. Filter to select ColumnA contains `a` and copy/paste what is visible into A1 of a new sheet. Delete ColumnA there. In A12 enter:

```
=OFFSET(A12,-10,)
```

Copy across and down to Row5001. Select sheet, Copy, and Paste Special, Values over the top. Select sheet and Sort on ColumnA.